# for loop for merging multiple dataframes using a for loop on a specific index

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop, merge

This is the data frame I am using:

```
df1 = ["Name": "John","Name": "Jack"]
df2 = ["Name": "Sam","Name": "Tom"]
df3 = ["Name": "Chloe","Name": "Vicky"]

list_of_dfs = [df1, df2, df3]
```

I tried using

```
df_final = reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on='client'), list_of_dfs)
```

I am getting following error:
"TypeError: Can only merge Series or DataFrame objects, a <class 'list'> was passed.

For some reason reduce() is not working. How can I loop it and merge multiple dataframes.

Answer (score 0):

`reduce` works. You need to see your input dataframes.

An example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([["a", 1],["b", 2]], columns=["column1", "column2"])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([["a", 4],["b", 5]], columns=["column1", "column3"])
df3 = pd.DataFrame([["a", 7],["b", 8]], columns=["column1", "column4"])

list_of_dfs = [df1, df2, df3]
```

The output of following code is:

```
reduce(lambda x, y: pd.merge(x,y, on='column1'), list_of_dfs)
```

> > 

```
column1 column2 column3 column4
0   a   1   4   7
1   b   2   5   8
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Maybe my code should have "on=Name". the df1 and df2 are based on certain values that I have already derived, how can create a list like df = [df1, df2, df3] using for loop? I need to have a for loop like for i in range(3): df = [df"{}".format(i)] and create this list. How can I do that?